# How to use the HSL (Hue Saturation Lightness) cylindric color model

Tags: r, colors

I would like to use the [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL) (Hue Saturation Lightness) color model (cylindric). Maybe I missed it, but I was not able to find a function that returns colors according to that scheme. `hcl` from the `colorspace` packages uses chroma not saturation. I would like to use a model, where maximal luminance/lightness will always return the color white as in the image below. ***How can I specify colors using the HSL model in R?***

TIA

**Add on**

What I get for different levels of luminance using `hcl` is this ([code here](https://gist.github.com/markheckmann/ad12685ee63cb47e9ebd)).
[image]

What I want is this the HSL model.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `RGB2HSL` in package `colorscience` is the only existing function for this conversion (Found by `library("sos")` then `findFn("HSL")`).

Comment: Is it possible that the function is `HLS` (from `colorspace`). There is some permutation in those 3 letters, but the function description is about hue, lightness, and saturation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adapted from wikipedia & java code, which (honestly) didn't take more than 90s (I timed it):

```
# specify h as whole input degrees (e.g 0-360)
# s = 0.0 - 1 (0 - 100%)
# l = 0.0 - 1, (0 - 100%)
# returns output from R's rgb() functin

hsl_to_rgb <- function(h, s, l) {
  h <- h / 360
  r <- g <- b <- 0.0
  if (s == 0) {
    r <- g <- b <- l
  } else {
    hue_to_rgb <- function(p, q, t) {
      if (t < 0) { t <- t + 1.0 }
      if (t > 1) { t <- t - 1.0 }
      if (t < 1/6) { return(p + (q - p) * 6.0 * t) }
      if (t < 1/2) { return(q) }
      if (t < 2/3) { return(p + ((q - p) * ((2/3) - t) * 6)) }
      return(p)
    }
    q <- ifelse(l < 0.5, l * (1.0 + s), l + s - (l*s))
    p <- 2.0 * l - q
    r <- hue_to_rgb(p, q, h + 1/3)
    g <- hue_to_rgb(p, q, h)
    b <- hue_to_rgb(p, q, h - 1/3)
  }
  return(rgb(r,g,b))
}

# r, g, b = 0.0 - 1 (0 - 100%)
# returns h/s/l in a vector, h = 0-360 deg, s = 0.0 - 1 (0-100%), l = 0.0 - 1 (0-100%)
rgb_to_hsl <- function(r, g, b) {
  val_max <- max(c(r, g, b))
  val_min <- min(c(r, g, b))
  h <- s <- l <- (val_max + val_min) / 2
  if (val_max == val_min){
    h <- s <- 0
  } else {
    d <- val_max - val_min
    s <- ifelse(l > 0.5, d / (2 - val_max - val_min), d / (val_max + val_min))
    if (val_max == r) { h <- (g - b) / d + (ifelse(g < b, 6, 0)) }
    if (val_max == g) { h <- (b - r) / d/ + 2 }
    if (val_max == b) { h <- (r - g) / d + 4 }
    h <- (h / 6) * 360
  }
  return(c(h=h, s=s, l=l))
}
```

Comment: Thank. But I guess for a guy who is not familiar with color spaces (like me) the time count would not use the measure `seconds` ;)

Comment: Aye. Not so much the understanding of the HSL as the pretty straightforward translation from Java to R (not much difference in the code examples)

Comment: Pretty sure line `if (val_max == g) { h <- (b - r) / d/ + 2 }` should be `if (val_max == g) { h <- (b - r) / d + 2 }`. Otherwise, very useful!